# Is cloverleaf antenna good for WIFI?

Tags: antenna, wifi

Is a [cloverleaf](http://blog.oscarliang.net/make-diy-cloverleaf-antenna/) antenna (that is used for [FPV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-person_view_(radio_control)) applications) good for home wifi?

[image]

If not, why?

Comment: A link to a cloverleaf antenna would be helpful, so would clarifying what FPV means.

Comment: FPV means First-person view.

http://blog.oscarliang.net/make-diy-cloverleaf-antenna/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WIFI transceivers generally use a linear polarized antennae. The cloverleaf antenna is circular, and, as the link states, suitable for transmitters. WIFI antenna ports in standard routers and access points are either bi-directional (RX and TX) or receive only.

Answer (score 2):

typically a clover leaf is used in a certain band of frequency range and WiFi can mean a wider range of frequencies that are possible based on your setup.  It is best to know your WiFi unit information to be able to recommend the best antenna.  Also need the application.  For instance, are you needing to have WiFi at a much greater distance than your current system allows?  Then a directional antenna or repeater may be necessary based on distance.  It is just hard to answer the question based on the amount of information.  Also, WiFi is a transceiver and transmits and receives whereas a clover leaf is generally a good transmitting antenna but may not be the best receive antenna.